# C++ Vector of Monsters

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

I want to make a vector where the type is my overloading constructor or to be precise I want to make a vector of monsters but I cant seem to pass it and I have no idea why. What did I do wrong?

```
// Monster.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Monster.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Random.h"
#include "Weapon.h"
using namespace std;

Monster::Monster(const std::string& name, int hp, int acc,
    int xpReward, int armor, const std::string& weaponName,
    int lowDamage, int highDamage, int monstergold)
{
    mName = name;
    mHitPoints = hp;
    mAccuracy = acc;
    mExpReward = xpReward;
    mArmor = armor;
    mWeapon.mName = weaponName;
    mWeapon.mDamageRange.mLow = lowDamage;
    mWeapon.mDamageRange.mHigh = highDamage;
    mGold = monstergold;
}
```

---

this is the map , if the roll was higher than 20, it should encounter a group of monsters

```
else if (roll > 20)
{
    vector <Monster(const std::string& name, int hp, int acc,int xpReward, int armor, const std::string& weaponName, int lowDamage, int highDamage, int monstergold)> MonsterArray;
    MonsterArray.push_back("Orc Lord", 25, 15, 2000, 5,"Two Handed Sword", 5, 20, 100);


    cout << "You encountered an multiple monsters!!!" << endl;
    cout << "Prepare for battle!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

---

the error was, it says that no overloaded function. I know this is wrong but I just really have no idea how to do it. any advice?

Comment: I think you need to [read a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn how to use template classes.

Comment: You should probably also learn about the [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) function. And read more about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify **typename** in the template rather than trying to call to the constructor:

```
// Here you define that vector will contain instances of Monster class  
vector<Monster> MonsterArray;

// Add new monster by explicitly calling 
// to the constructor and pushing into container
MonsterArray.push_back(Monster("Orc Lord", 25, 15, 2000, 5,"Two Handed Sword", 5, 20, 100));
```

While I'd suggest to read [The C++ Programming Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) book.

---

Also it seems that you are missing include of the vector container, e.g.:

```
#include <vector>
```

Comment: oh my god, that works, welp that was easy, I have a question, what is the diffrence between "Monster" inside the "<>" of the vector compared to the "Monster()" , I know that the "Monster()" is a constructor but I'd like to know what is their difference and uses. Example I have a class "Player" then there is also a constructor "Player()" I declared a Player type outside the class, so it should go like this, Player mainPlayer, this is a object right? In this case, I am not adding "()" to the vector so does that mean I am declaring a group of object?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to read the book. When you are using templates then in <> braces you usually (depends on template) define the typename to substitute into template parameter. Now, then you defining Player mainPlayer; it implicitly calls to the default constructor. But to be precise there are much more than I can capture in the comment and it cannot replace the book.

Comment: When you have a class that has a default constructor and you declare a variable of that type, that is what you have a variable or object either on the stack or in heap in most cases. Even when you see code like: `Player player;` by default it is calling `Player player();` now when you see a class's typename within template parameters such as your basic containers `std::vector<Player>` or `std::vector<Monster>` or even pointers to them: `std::vector<Player*>` or `std::vector<Monster*>` these are not instances of the class, these are typenames or pointers to a type.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify all parameters of your Monster class  while  declaring your vector. 
Simply do something like that :

```
std::vector<Monster> monsters;
monsters.push_back(new Monster("Orc Lord", 25, 15, 2000, 5,"Two Handed Sword", 5, 20, 100));
```